# Should a username be truncated?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, copywriting, username, truncation

Is it ever OK to truncate a username?  Is there any good solution / trade-off?

---

Site shows username as:
Username: Shrinivasuk View: Shrinivasu...

[image]

Username: Ritesh View: Rite
Username: Poonam View: Poona
Username: Deepak View: Deepa
Username: sourab View: sour

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'can it be truncated'. Clearly yes, it can. What exactly is the UX problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Isn't it misleading? Participants are Dilip, Sadiq,Anand,Rite,Poona,Atul,Deepa,Viraj,Sour (visible) different from their actual names. I think user don't go for the second fold unless he gets the right name

Comment: @JonW he wants to know if they should be allowed to be truncated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If at all possible, you should **avoid truncating a unique name**.  Restricting usernames to a maximum length is one way of dealing with this.

However, if you have some very long usernames:

- **don't wrap the elipsis** (…) to another line.  This makes it appear at first glance that the full username is visible, and is likely to cause confusion.
- you should make sure that selecting the name takes you to a **profile** for that user which contains their full username.  If you don't do this, you make is even easier to impersonate other users and end up with a major administration hassle.

Answer (score 5):

Truncating a username **is a bad idea**. Usernames are used to uniquely identify a person on your site, so if you're randomly hiding part of the name, that's **defeating the whole purpose** of the username.

With such a limited amount of space like the example posted here, it would be more effective to just **get rid of the usernames** altogether, and only show the pictures (linking to the profile on click, and tooltipping the username wouldn't hurt either).

If there is a little bit more space available, then @JohnGB's suggestion of **not wrapping the ellipsis** is critical. Maybe even fade out the username into the ellipsis to make it extra clear that something is missing. But this should be a rare occurrence. If usernames are frequently getting truncated, the design is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to write "not at all"... but in some cases as "Surio Mario Martinez Chuenez Ferdinando" could be necessary.

Username is/should/could be used as unique identifier so therefore should not be truncated by design.

Key solution for that is in restricting username to a certain length in the time of analysis and design to avoid the necessity of truncating it in some future report.

If the user is allowed to define a username (not the real name) as the example above, then it could be evaluated as the wrong design.

A workaround could be to display tooltip on mouseover... and if you are the developer, you should definitely see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446624/table-cell-widths-fixing-width-wrapping-truncating-long-words)

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend truncating username. Some other way to avoid this issue is to impose a hard limit on the length of username.

Failing to do so will just introduce many other issues to system usability such as

- inability to distinguish similar usernames that have been truncated
- impersonation
- increase chance of users committing errors (e.g. opening the wrong page)
- confusion with elipsis